# Slice a json's data using react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an api that returns this json below, what I'm trying to do is that I just take the "name" that json returns and put it in a text component. I've tried to do it but it returns null or full json.

```
{
      "user": {
        "_id": "1",
        "name": "User Name",
        "email": "user@test.com",
      }
    }



const [cars, setCars] = useState([]);

    async function loadCars() {
        const response = await api.get('me');

        setCars(response.data);
    }
```

Comment: Does `response` contain that json you show above, or `response.data`?

Comment: what is 'me' and where is the text component that you are trying to put the name in. Also, there is no reference to the `name` on your code, did you mean `setCars(response.data.name)`. It is not clear what you are currently doing that isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since some of the code is abstracted I'm assuming that 'response.data' is the JSON object you posted above? If so you could simply change `setCars` from the `response.data` value to the field that you're looking to capture in state

As in:

```js
    async function loadCars() {
        const response = await api.get('me');
        setCars(response.data.user.name);
    }
```

In this example you're also initializing state to an empty array, so you might consider aligning it with it's future value and either using `useState("")` or `useState(null)` so that your conditional rendering is based on if state has a string with a value, or is simply no longer null. Either way it's not relevant in regards to your true question.

More on hooks here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html